# average value of harmonic function around a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I am self-studying this class notes on MIT OCW https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-112-functions-of-a-complex-variable-fall-2008/lecture-notes/lecture16.pdf . This question is taken from the above notes, in which there is a step I do not understand.

Theorem 20 in the notes:

If $u$ harmonic in $\Omega= \{z: r_1 \leq |z-z_0| \leq r_2\} \subset \mathbb C$, then $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+re^{i\theta}) d\theta =  \alpha \log r + \beta$ for all $r_1 \leq r \leq r_2$. The note gives the following justification, by writing the Laplacian in polar coordinate form:

$\triangle = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+ \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}$.

Then, writing $V(r)= LHS = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+re^{i\theta}) d\theta$, it says $\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = 0$.

The above step is the one I do not get. I think it is trying to say that $V$ is harmonic, and then apply the Laplacian $\triangle$ to $V$, so since $V$ is independent of $\theta$, the last term disappears and we get $\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = 0$. However, I am not sure how to show that $V$ is harmonic.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is showing that the integral evaluates to the $\alpha \log(r)+\beta$.  They are showing that $V(r)$ (the integral) satisfies the ODE
$$V_{rr} + \frac{1}{r}v_r = 0.$$
If you solve this ODE for $V(r)$, you will get exactly the $\alpha \log(r)+\beta$.

The fact that $V$ is harmonic comes from the fact that $u$ is harmonic.  Basically, they are taking the Laplacian operator inside the integral.

Comment: Yeah I get the steps after that. But I do not know how to get $\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial r} = 0$

Comment: That's what I thought too,  but I could not justify putting the Laplacian inside the integral. Can you show the steps how you obtain the uniform convergence to put the Laplacian inside?

Comment: Good point.  I don't know all the details.  I will work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$u(z_0+re^{i\theta})=u(r,\theta),\quad 
V(r)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}u\ \mathrm{d}\theta,$$
then
$$\triangle u=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\theta^2}=0,$$
$$V_r=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}u_r\ \mathrm{d}\theta,\quad
V_{rr}=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}u_{rr}\ \mathrm{d}\theta,$$
and we get:
$$V_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}V_r
=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\left(u_{rr}
+\frac{u_r}{r}\right)\ \mathrm{d}\theta
=\frac{-1}{2\pi r^2}\int_0^{2\pi}u_{\theta\theta}\ \mathrm{d}\theta\\
=\frac{-1}{2\pi r^2}[u_{\theta}(r,2\pi)-u_{\theta}(r,0)]=0.$$

In the following, just solve the ODE:
$$V_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}V_r=0.$$
Note that
$$V_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}V_r=0\iff rV_{rr}+V_r=0\iff (rV_r)'=0,$$
this implies $rV_r\equiv a,$ i.e. $V_r=\frac{a}{r},$
so
$$V(r)=\int_{r_1}^{r}\frac{a}{r}\ \mathrm{d}r+V(r_1)=a\log r+b.$$